# Showing error message when uploaded file size exceeds maxRequestLength

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, valums-file-uploader

I have written this in web.config:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="10240" executionTimeout="30" />
```

On client side I'm using valum's AjaxUpload plugin. When using IE 9 I can't check uploading file size with JavaScript, because IE 9 does not support this. So if I upload large file with IE, server will throw exception because of above setting written in web.config. How can I catch this exception and show message to user? thanks in advance

Comment: The response code should be different from the server (200), you should be able to catch the response code to present your message

Comment: The plugin is using hidden iframe, so I cannot get status code. Additionally it throws this error only when exception is thrown on server side: `Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL data:text/html,chromewebdata from frame with URL [my url]. The frame requesting access has a protocol of 'http', the frame being accessed has a protocol of ''. Protocols must match.`

Comment: What version of this plug in?  It sounds like you may be using an old non-official version.

Answer (score 0):

On this page [Ajax Upload using valums ajax upload plugin inside a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227307/ajax-upload-using-valums-ajax-upload-plugin-inside-a-form) could you not use the `onComplete` section to find the response code?

```
onComplete: function(file, response) {
    // --- stuff here too
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using valums file uploader then you can specify file size limit in plugin options.

```
sizeLimit: 0, // max size   
minSizeLimit: 0, // min size
```

And in case of any error you also can handle it onError: function()...